# Error Next.js getting 500 error on deploying the project in aws-amplify

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, web, next.js, aws-amplify

Hi i am getting module missing error

**Error: Cannot find module 'next/dist/server/next-server'**

https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-hosting/issues/3319

the build is getting generated successfully, please do let me know how to solve it.

[image]

Comment: what version of nextjs you are using ?

Comment: Next.js 13.1.1 version we are using

Comment: Have you tried building it locally and seeing whether it works when running it?

Comment: The build is getting generated successfully in local and production

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the build settings in amplify. If it's the build settings, you should only see `yarn install` in preBuild. Try replacing that code with `rm -rf node_modules -rf yarn.lock && yarn install --frozen-lockfile`.